# .htaccess exclude a directory to be rewrited

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

where I'm wrong in this htaccess, because /assets/ folder isn't excluded from rewrite rule.
When I access: http://www.site.com/assets/images/sidebar1/some/pic.pngs isn't return 404 as I expected.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(assets|css)/
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule says :

rewrite everything to index.php when :

The URL is not a file and is not a directory and is not in `/assets/` or `/css/`.

The file you're asking is not a file, not a directory and is in `assets/`:

So ok for the rule, BUT! your log show you are then asking for `/home/valentin/public_html/404.shtml`  (automatic redirection for the unknown object!)

And this request goes through the rules again!

It is not a file (!-f matched), not a directory (!-d matched) and it is not in `assets/` nor in `css/` then it gets rewritten to index.php

Q.E.D.

You can correct this by putting the 404.shtml in your `public_html/` folder, or change this in apache configuration to a real file.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i added 404.shtml in folder then i`ve got same thing. Isn`t posible to get an browser 404 not a cusom one? http://www.valentinivascu.ro/rewrite.txt see new log please

Comment: I think the 404.shtml is indexed somewhere in the apache configuration. Search for something like 'ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml` in your config files.

Comment: Yes, thanks, seems that was the problem. The customized ErrorDocument from apache :) Have a nice day